# Check a value and return the same value if condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas

```
ColA
10
15
16
Ar
55
Et
Al
99
```

How to check if the row has number and return same number else return 0 in pandas

Expected output

```
ColB
10
15
16
0
55
0
0
99
```

Comment: try : `pd.to_numeric(df['ColB'],errors='coerce').fillna(0)#.astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `apply`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df

d = df({'ColA': ['10','15','16','Ar','55','Et','Al','99']})

print(d['ColA'].apply(lambda x: x if x.isdigit() else 0))
```

Output:

```
0    10
1    15
2    16
3     0
4    55
5     0
6     0
7    99
Name: ColA, dtype: object
```

---

From @anky in the comments:

> Pandas also has a `str.isdigit()` method:
>
> ```
> d['ColA'].where(d['ColA'].str.isdigit(),0)
> ```

Comment: Pandas also has a `str.isdigit()` method :- `d['ColA'].where(d['ColA'].str.isdigit(),0)`